# The best way to store "app secret" in a mobile web application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, app-secret

I want to develop a "***responsive mobile web application (iOS / Android)***" with JavaScript to interact with Smart Contract and blockchain.

I decided to develop a hybrid mobile web application. ***However, the question is how to store the App Secret safe in case of developing a mobile web application with JavaScript ?*** Since, we do not want to store it in the mobile and blockchain because of security.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to develop a "responsive mobile web application (iOS / Android)" with JavaScript to interact with Smart Contract and blockchain.

Is not clear for me if you are referring to write the Mobile Application as a web site that is full responsive in mobile or if you are considering to write it using a framework like Ionic, React Native or others.

If is a responsive website than please ignore the rest of my answer once there is no secure way of securing secrets on them, as far as I am aware.

Now if is a cross platform Mobile App done with any of the many available frameworks, than keep reading because a possible solution exists to solve the problem of secrets on them.

> However, the question is how to store the App Secret safe in case of developing a mobile web application with JavaScript ?

Anything running on the client side will be vulnerable to reverse engineering with tools like [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/) or [Frida](https://frida.re).

> Since, we do not want to store it in the mobile and blockchain because of security.

As already pointed out by you the Mobile or Blockchain are not good places to store the App Secret.

## A Possible Solution

To harden the communication between your Mobile App and the API server you should use a Mobile App Attestation service, that will guarantee at run-time that your App was not modified or is not running in a jail broken or rooted device, by using an SDK integrated in you App and a service running in the cloud.

The cloud service on successful attestation of the App integrity issues a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) that is signed with a secret that only the API server and the cloud service are aware and on failure the JWT token is signed with a fake secret that the API server does not know. This approach will allow for the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the cloud attestation service is not known by the Mobile App it is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time, even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

On [this article](https://www.approov.io/blog/first-experiences-with-react-native-bridging-an-android-native-module-for-app-authentication.html) you can walk through example of how a Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud is used to authenticate a React Native App.

Disclaimer: I work at Approov

[Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo. As all changes are done in the memory, you just need to deactivate the module and reboot to get your original system back. There are many other advantages, but here is just one more: Multiple modules can do changes to the same part of the system or app. With modified APKs, you to decide for one. No way to combine them, unless the author builds multiple APKs with different combinations.

[Frida](https://frida.re)

> Dynamic instrumentation toolkit for developers, reverse-engineers, and security researchers.

[JWT Token](https://jwt.io/)

> Token Based Authentication
>
> JSON Web Tokens are an open, industry standard RFC 7519 method for representing claims securely between two parties.